# Laptop won't detect wifi after an issue with WiFiKill

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

My brother used WiFiKill on my laptop as a prank. I think I turned it off by simply clicking Start on the top middle of the page, to change it from Start to Stop. I thought that had solved the problem but when I went back to my laptop, it showed "No Networks Found" (whereas before, I was connected, but pages weren't loading AT ALL). So I told my father about it and he got my brother to remove the app immediately. I thought that should have solved it, but my laptop still can't detect any WiFi networks (including our neighbors') now. What should I do?

Comment: try rebooting your laptop

Comment: Hi Patricia, welcome to [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com). I've edited your question to match the style of other questions on this site. If I removed important details, then feel free to click "edit" and put them back!

Comment: Leaving your OS open for other people's tinkering is unsafe, your brother could as well install a hidden spyware on your laptop. I would advise completely clearing the drive, installing OS from the original source, enable full disk encryption with a strong password, also use another strong password for the OS user, and never keep the session unlocked while you are not near your laptop. That way, it would be incredibly harder for other people to install unwanted stuff on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting the network driver from device manager if the program had a effect on the driver's functionality. Usually if you're unable to find a connection through Wifi at all, resetting the driver can help. Definitely confirm the software is gone though. If not, even with the driver reset you'll still have issues with connections.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specs of the computer in question. the only things i can suggest is flushing(reseting it to default) the wifi network configuration in case someone hid all the networks. flushing the arp cache on your computer and resting the drivers wireless Network Interface.